# Regular Expression to replace specific '.' notations to '_'

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I have a string `Mr. $m.Name$ stays at $m.Address.City$`

I want to replace the `.` notations in the above string which are not immediately preceded by `$m` but fall within the `$` delimiter. I want to replace such `.` notations with an `_` notation.

This is the result I expect for the above string : `Mr. $m.Name$ stays at $m.Address_City$`
but i'm not able to figure out the right expression to make this work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<!\$m)\.(?=\S)
```

Try this.This will work in `C#`.Use verbatinum mode with `@`.See demo.Replace with `_`.

https://regex101.com/r/pM9yO9/17

Answer (score 0):

This is an example using sed

```
    echo 'Mr. $m.Name$ stays at $m.Address.City$ m.' | sed "s/[^m]\./_/g"
 | sed "s/[^$]m./m_/g"
```